# Freeware to convert large number of images to video

Tags: image, video

Can anyone suggest any freeware to convert large number of images into a video?

I have around 3000 images in png format each of size around 30 kb. I want to convert these into a video, with the requirement that the frame rate be a configurable parameter.

I tried Windows Movie Maker and iMovie on MAC but both seem to get stuck in exporting the video and importing the images respectively.

Any other freeware tools that can be suggested for this purpose? I need to generate about 50 such videos, so no divide and conquer solutions please!

Thanks

Comment: MenCoder; http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/menc-feat-enc-images.html

Comment: This has to be worked up from source or is there a downloadable executable? Pl post a link if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=34) is a good one for such operations.

Comment: I tried this, it works but has the problem that exported avi file is very large (of the order of 1gb+). I tried applying compression after installing xvid codec but then there is too much blockiness in the video. Would you have any ideas to resolve?

Comment: I am not a video expert, but VirtualDub can show all available configuration options for every codec used. You have to use "Video" -> "Full Processing Mode" and then configure the codec using "Video" -> "Compression".